# How to ask the user to choose a file, and store the choice using tkinter?

Tags: python, python-3.x, file, user-interface, tkinter

Creating an automated dashboard, all the functionalities are ready but **I want the user to select the excel file and store that choice, unless clicked on change file**

```
   path = filedialog.askopenfile(filetypes = (("Text files", "*.txt"), ("All files", "*.*"))).name
```

i tried certain things, but it doesnt save the choice, so if any of you can suggest the methodology to do it using tkinter

Comment: You need to share the **certain things** in a form of code and someone can help you for sure :)

Comment: shared @Gameplay

Comment: It's not clear what you're asking here. As written in the code you provided, `path` will be set to the selected file (an `_io.TextIOWrapper` object, to be more specific), or to `None` if the user cancels selection / closes the dialog window. Given your question, this is the correct way to do what you want. Is there some other problem you're having? What is the expected / desired behavior? You say you **tried certain things** - what things? It's always easier to provide help if we know what you tried! Please see [ask] and read about [mre] if you're not sure what sort of info to add.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Implement it by yourself using the `initialdir`, `initialfile`, and `filetypes` options.

This is an example for the first two.

```
import os
from tkinter import filedialog

last_path = ''
def ask_path_to_open(path=''):
    global last_path
    options = dict(filetypes=[('*.py', '*.py'), ('All', '*.*')])
    path = path or last_path
    if path:
        options.update(
            initialdir=os.path.dirname(path),
            initialfile=os.path.basename(path),
        )
    path = filedialog.askopenfilename(**options)
    last_path = path or ''
    return last_path

print(ask_path_to_open())
print(ask_path_to_open())
```